# Can I get heap dump of a java process from a remote server without jdk installed?

Tags: java, jvm, rmi, heap-dump

I have a server with JRE, I need to get heap dump, without hanging application, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Depends on platform and vendor. On Linux a specific kill signal often does this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jattach](https://github.com/apangin/jattach/) utility can do that.
It works without JDK installed.

```
jattach <pid> dumpheap /path/to/dump.hprof
```

Note: JVM will be paused while dumping the heap. As soon as the dump is completed, application will resume.